# Join a temporary table to query result in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to SQL and looking for a simple/succinct way to achieve the following:

I have a query which has a nested select statement, and this nested select returns the data to a temporary table. I would for this temp table to be joined onto the initial return, however, I am just unsure about how I would achieve this.

```
SELECT Profile.profilename as Recipient, 
Message.messagetext as MessageText, 
message.datesent as DateSent

FROM Profile 
INNER JOIN
Message ON Profile.profile_id = Message.profile_idtoo
WHERE Message.profile_idfrom = 3

(
SELECT profilename  from Profile
    Inner JOIN 
    Message on Profile.profile_id = Message.profile_idfrom
    WHERE Message.profile_idfrom = 3
)
```

--Create tables and data.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Message](
    [message_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [messagetext] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [datesent] [date] NOT NULL,
    [profile_idtoo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [profile_idfrom] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Message_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [message_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Profile]    Script Date: 20/11/2018 13:14:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Profile](
    [profile_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [profilename] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [regdate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Profile_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [profile_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Message] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Message] ([message_id], [messagetext], [datesent], [profile_idtoo], [profile_idfrom]) VALUES (1, N'This playlist is the best', CAST(N'2018-11-13' AS Date), 9, 8)
INSERT [dbo].[Message] ([message_id], [messagetext], [datesent], [profile_idtoo], [profile_idfrom]) VALUES (2, N'I got superscared by a few of those moviews tbh', CAST(N'2017-12-14' AS Date), 2, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[Message] ([message_id], [messagetext], [datesent], [profile_idtoo], [profile_idfrom]) VALUES (3, N'I think you should look atmy playlist called "the best songs of all time". ', CAST(N'2017-09-14' AS Date), 2, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[Message] ([message_id], [messagetext], [datesent], [profile_idtoo], [profile_idfrom]) VALUES (4, N'Best thing I ever done signin up to this site!', CAST(N'2018-11-13' AS Date), 6, 7)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Message] OFF
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Profile] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Profile] ([profile_id], [profilename], [regdate], [user_id]) VALUES (1, N'TheSpazzCommander', CAST(N'2017-02-01' AS Date), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Profile] ([profile_id], [profilename], [regdate], [user_id]) VALUES (2, N'CaptainBuzzkill', CAST(N'2015-01-01' AS Date), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Profile] ([profile_id], [profilename], [regdate], [user_id]) VALUES (3, N'EVLM', CAST(N'2018-08-15' AS Date), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Profile] ([profile_id], [profilename], [regdate], [user_id]) VALUES (4, N'JBlunt', CAST(N'2017-07-15' AS Date), 3)
INSERT [dbo].[Profile] ([profile_id], [profilename], [regdate], [user_id]) VALUES (5, N'JaneHeart', CAST(N'2015-05-01' AS Date), 4)
INSERT [dbo].[Profile] ([profile_id], [profilename], [regdate], [user_id]) VALUES (6, N'JimmyHeart', CAST(N'2015-01-05' AS Date), 4)
INSERT [dbo].[Profile] ([profile_id], [profilename], [regdate], [user_id]) VALUES (7, N'Khall', CAST(N'2014-01-01' AS Date), 6)
INSERT [dbo].[Profile] ([profile_id], [profilename], [regdate], [user_id]) VALUES (8, N'thehunter', CAST(N'2017-01-01' AS Date), 7)
INSERT [dbo].[Profile] ([profile_id], [profilename], [regdate], [user_id]) VALUES (9, N'thehunterswife', CAST(N'2017-01-01' AS Date), 7)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Profile] OFF
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Message]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [message_Profile_from] FOREIGN KEY([profile_idfrom])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Profile] ([profile_id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Message] CHECK CONSTRAINT [message_Profile_from]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Message]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [message_Profile_too] FOREIGN KEY([profile_idtoo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Profile] ([profile_id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Message] CHECK CONSTRAINT [message_Profile_too]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Profile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Profile_User] FOREIGN KEY([user_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([user_id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Profile] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Profile_User]
GO
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic that does not describe a non-functioning query.

Comment: I will dig out sample data, essentially the query functions and returns what I want however, I just want to join the second select onto the initial select so I am not returned two tables when I run the query.

Comment: Your code does not contain, reference, or create ANY temporary table or table variable, so it is not clear what your goal is. "Join" also has a specific meaning, but I get the impression you want to simply combine 2 resultsets into 1. Generate the rows of the first query and then add into that set the additional rows from the second query. If so, the union operator might be useful. But I think you may be trying to hard to be clever or efficient (or worse).

Comment: My lecturer told me that the second select is classed as a temporary table. You are indeed correct, I just want to combine the results returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1f45d9dfb772a2545ee164dc1a8f6b5c)**

```
    SELECT Profile.profile_id,Profile.profilename as Recipient, m1.profilename,
Message.messagetext as MessageText, 
message.datesent as DateSent
FROM Profile 
INNER JOIN
Message ON Profile.profile_id = Message.profile_idtoo
inner join (SELECT profile_id,profilename  from Profile
    Inner JOIN 
    Message on Profile.profile_id = Message.profile_idfrom
    WHERE Message.profile_idfrom = 3) m1 on Message.profile_idfrom = m1.profile_id
WHERE Message.profile_idfrom = 3
```

Comment: I gave this a try, it returned no data to me. This is my first SQL post, so I think I need to provide more content.

Comment: @SimonDean yes, that would be great to help

Comment: Would the table and insert scripts be enough for someone to work with? Sorry for my green hue.

Comment: @SimonDean, that will be enough. but if you can provide your expected output  then that will be more helpful

Comment: I have updated the post with table and insert scripts, I have tried union but as I am returning 3 items with the first select and then 1 with the second union is not able to work.

Comment: @SimonDean - I've edited my answer - also you can check now - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1f45d9dfb772a2545ee164dc1a8f6b5c

Comment: I see how this works! I needed Alias (If this is the correct word) for the joined table be referenced in the initial select? Also, ty for raising my awareness of DB fiddle!

Comment: @SimonDean, yes you can do that

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what else you want from the second table in your result set this may also work...keep in mind you have inner joins from the same table on two different fields, you may be excluding results or it may be the intended result :) More info would be helpful!

```
SELECT  PROFILE.profilename AS Recipient, 
        MessageToo.messagetext AS MessageText, 
        MessageToo.datesent AS DateSent
FROM PROFILE
INNER JOIN Message MessageToo ON PROFILE.profile_id = Message.profile_idtoo
INNER JOIN Message MessageFrom ON PROFILE.profile_id = Message.profile_idfrom
WHERE Message.profile_idfrom = 3
```

---

```
SELECT  PROFILE.profilename AS Recipient, 
        MessageToo.messagetext AS MessageText, 
        MessageToo.datesent AS DateSent
FROM PROFILE
LEFT JOIN Message MessageToo ON PROFILE.profile_id = Message.profile_idtoo
WHERE PROFILE.profile_idfrom = 3
```

Comment: I am deliberately trying to exclude results, as the intention is to show all messages sent from user 3 to destination user.

Comment: If that is what you need you may not need the second table join? I added additional logic above.

Comment: The initial select query I posted, returns the following: 

Recipient, Message and Date Sent. However, I am also trying to return the name of the user who sent the message (the name exists in the profile table). The FK to be referenced when returning the name of the sender is the Message.profile_idfrom.